# Botão voltar sem action bar

Tags: android

Retirei a action bar de uma única acitivity. Mas na minha Action bar tem o botão voltar. Se eu retirar a action bar logicamente o botão sai junto. Mas gostaria que o botão **voltar**, ficasse ali. Existe algum toolbar ou algo do tipo em que o botão voltar fique transparente e permaneça ?.
Estou desenhando uma tela de detalhamento do cadastro de um cliente.
Segue as imagens para melhor entendimento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: Toolbar está ficando na frente agora]

Código do XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está usando a Toolbar ou a ActionBar mesmo? Se estiver usando a Toolbar você pode setar o background dela como transparente. Já se estiver usando a ActionBar mesmo aconselho que mude para a Toolbar pois é bem mais fácil de customizá-la.

Comment: Eai @Bruno. Estou utilizando action bar. Vou refazer meu código todo então e no lugar da Action vou utilizar o Toolbar. Agradeço.

Comment: Estude os modos imersivos: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html acho que trará mais usabilidade ao que você pretende fazer.

Comment: @Mateus, vou da uma conferida aqui. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Bruno, implantei o toolbar no meu projeto. Porém quando chega na parte do ListView, ele ultrapassa o toolbar. Existe algum comando para fixar o toolbar ?

Comment: Com 'ultrapassa' voce quer dizer que o ListView fica atrás da Toolbar?

Comment: @Bruno, isto mesmo. Consegui resolver. Apenas peguei o código de toolbar e coloquei depois do código do ListView. Deu certo. Mas ficou muito estranho. Sem sombreamento no toolbar. E a lista agora ultrapassa o toolbar, porém não fica na frente. Coloquei a imagem na minha pergunta acima.

Comment: naõ entendi exatamente o que você quer. Quer que fique somente o botão? Se for isso, deixe a toolbar transparente  com  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent"

Comment: @LeonardoAssunção Entendi o seu argumento. Porém consigo deixar o toolbar transparente somente nesta tela ? Criei um arquivo chamado toolbar e reutilizo ele em outras tela com o comando <include. Dará certo ?

Comment: Colocando esse tema, somente a toolbar desse layout ficará transparente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:
Envolva sua `Toolbar` com o `AppBarLayout`

```
      <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            // ... Sua ToolBar vai aqui

      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

E abaixo do `AppBarLayout` você adiciona seu `ListView` com a propriedade `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`:

```
<ListView
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    ...>

 </ListView>
```

Comment: Bruno, tentei realizar o procedimento como você me falou e me retorna o seguinte erro:

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: Me mostre seu xml, pois esse erro normalmente é erro de escrita.

Comment: Só lembrando que sua chamada no xml da Toolbar tem que ser assim: <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar. E no seu codigo java o import tambem tem que ser: import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: Bruno, eu coloquei o que você me mostrou ai no meu código o toolbar e ainda me retorna o mesmo erro. Lá encima da minha pergunta, editei e coloquei o xml do toolbar. Dá uma conferida lá. Obrigado.

Comment: E no seu codigo java o import esta como mostrei acima? se puder mostre a linha que esta ocorrendo o erro.

Comment: O erro que voce descreveu, está dizendo que voce não pode converter um AppBarLayout em uma Toolbar, isso normalmente acontece quando o seu import está chamando uma versao antiga da Toolbar, em vez da livraria de suporte v7.

Comment: Bruno, também achei isso. Fui lá no meu código Java e o import dele está correto como você soliciou. import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

Comment: Mostre o xml inteiro.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41730/discussion-between-artur-mafezzoli-junior-and-bruno).

Comment: Coloquei lá no chat. Pode ser ?

Answer (score 0):

Tente esse código

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"      
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

E no styles.xml adicione

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Leonardo, fiz o que você me solicitou sim. No meu Java também importei a classe como você pediu. Tirei um print. Coloquei ali na minha pergunta. Ultimo print. O toolbar ainda fica sobreposto encima do meu listview e ainda trocou de cor. Mas a cor é o de menos.

Comment: tira android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" para tirar a cor. Foi erro meu e já editei. Você quer que o list view fique abaixo da toolbar? Ou seja, que ela não sobreponha o listview?

Comment: Isso mesmo. o Listview sobrepõem o toolbar. Mas acho que deva ser alguma problema no toolbar, pois quando utilizava o action bar ele ia certinho.

Comment: tente usar um relative layout e colocar  no listview android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"